# Xcode App Crashes with error randomly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm making an iPhone app in objective c and have run in to an issue. Every 15 or so runs, it throws a random error saying "libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception". I can't track down which code is causing this, as it's random and not very often. I've run the zombie profiler on it and there are no zombies. I'm using ARC. Can anybody offer any advice for finding the cause of this?

Thanks

Comment: It gives only this error message?

Comment: Is Xcode crashing or is your iPhone app crashing?

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when you drag a project folder to another location. Then when you run the project it crashes, probably because the location of some Xcode file (still totally unknown to me) doesn't match.

Try creating your project from scratch: create a new project and add all the files that you have created inside it. And never displace it to another location.

Answer (score 0):

This is a C++ exception. You can debug it setting a C++ exception breakpoint (Add Exception Breakpoint -> C++ in Breakpoint Navigator).